# Processing 3.2.1, biblioteca Game Control Plus, java exception

Tags: java, exceção, controller

Boas!

Estou a estudar Games & Apps Development e no nosso primeiro semestre estamos a fazer um jogo em Processing.
No meu jogo estou a usar um comando da PS4 com a ajuda da biblioteca [Game Control Plus](http://lagers.org.uk/gamecontrol/index.html).
Se eu carregar num botão vezes suficientes, o meu jogo crasha e dá-me isto na consola: (o plug 'Uarma' é a função que executa o código quando se carrega no botão)

> ```
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>     at org.gamecontrolplus.Plug.call(Unknown Source)
>     at org.gamecontrolplus.ControlButton.callPlugs(Unknown Source)
>     at org.gamecontrolplus.ControlButton.update(Unknown Source)
>     at org.gamecontrolplus.ControlDevice.update(Unknown Source)
>     at org.gamecontrolplus.ControlIO.run(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
> Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError
>     at org.jbox2d.dynamics.World.createBody(World.java:339)
>     at shiffman.box2d.Box2DProcessing.createBody(Box2DProcessing.java:203)
>     at Meon$Bullet.<init>(Meon.java:202)
>     at Meon.Uarma(Meon.java:294)
>     ... 9 more
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Error on calling plug: Uarma
>     at org.gamecontrolplus.Plug.call(Unknown Source)
>     at org.gamecontrolplus.ControlButton.callPlugs(Unknown Source)
>     at org.gamecontrolplus.ControlButton.update(Unknown Source)
>     at org.gamecontrolplus.ControlDevice.update(Unknown Source)
>     at org.gamecontrolplus.ControlIO.run(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
> ```

O meu conhecimento de Java não é muito, por isso qualquer ajuda acerca do que poderá estar a causar este erro é apreciada!

Desde já, obrigado!

Aqui vai todo o código envolvido no processo:

```java
//Variaveis
ControlIO controlo;
ControlDevice comando;

//inicia o ControlIO (vai ver que comandos estao ligados)
controlo = ControlIO.getInstance(this);

//procura comandos compativeis
comando = controlo.getMatchedDevice("playerControl");

//associa funçoes a botoes (Botão para Função)
BpFp1(); //p1 = player 1

void BpFp1() {

  comando.getButton("jump").plug(this, "salto", ControlIO.ON_PRESS);
  comando.getButton("punch").plug(this, "murro", ControlIO.ON_PRESS);
  comando.getButton("grabWep").plug(this, "Aarma", ControlIO.ON_PRESS);
  comando.getButton("useWep").plug(this, "Uarma", ControlIO.ON_PRESS);
}

void Uarma() {

  println("usar armas? check");  
  bullets.add(new Bullet(player1.playerPos.x + 20, player1.playerPos.y, 5, 5));
}
```

Construtor Bullet:

```java
class Bullet {

  Vec2 bulletPos;
  Body bulletbody;
  float dbulletLarg;
  float dbulletAlt;

  Bullet(float bulletX, float bulletY, float bulletLarg, float bulletAlt) {

    //definir o corpo
    BodyDef bulletbd = new BodyDef();
    bulletbd.type = BodyType.DYNAMIC;
    bulletbd.bullet = true;
    bulletbd.position.set(box2d.coordPixelsToWorld(bulletX, bulletY));

    //criar o corpo
    bulletbody = box2d.createBody(bulletbd);

    //forma
    PolygonShape bulletps = new PolygonShape();
    bulletps.setAsBox(box2d.scalarPixelsToWorld(bulletLarg/2), box2d.scalarPixelsToWorld(bulletAlt/2));


    //o que cola a forma ao corpo
    FixtureDef bulletfd = new FixtureDef();
    bulletfd.shape = bulletps;

    //parametros que afetam a fisica do objeto
    bulletfd.density = 0;

    //colar a forma ao corpo
    bulletbody.createFixture(bulletfd);

    dbulletLarg = bulletLarg;
    dbulletAlt = bulletAlt;

    bulletbody.applyLinearImpulse(new Vec2(100, 0), bulletbody.getWorldCenter(), true);
  }

  void display() {

    bulletPos = box2d.getBodyPixelCoord(bulletbody);

    pushMatrix();
    translate(bulletPos.x, bulletPos.y);
    rectMode(CENTER);
    rect(0, 0, dbulletLarg, dbulletAlt);
    popMatrix();
  }
}
```

Aqui vai a classe Meon inteira:

```java
//Sprites: biblioteca de sprites (arte do jogo)
import sprites.*;
import sprites.maths.*;
import sprites.utils.*;

//Box2D for Processing: biblioteca de physX (mais outra)
import shiffman.box2d.*;
import org.jbox2d.collision.shapes.*;
import org.jbox2d.common.*;
import org.jbox2d.dynamics.*;
import org.jbox2d.dynamics.contacts.*;

//Game Control Plus: biblioteca controlo (ps4 neste caso)
import net.java.games.input.*;
import org.gamecontrolplus.*;
import org.gamecontrolplus.gui.*;

//Variaveis
ControlIO controlo;
ControlDevice comando;
ControlDevice comando2;

Box2DProcessing box2d;

float fx1;
float fx2;

Player player1;
Player player2;

Platform floor;
Platform sideRight;
Platform sideLeft;
Platform ceiling;

//s: small, m: medium,  b: big | b: bottom, m: middle, t: top
Platform stleft;
Platform smleft;
Platform sbleft;

Platform stright;
Platform smright;
Platform sbright;

Platform mbleft;
Platform mtleft;

Platform mbright;
Platform mtright;

Platform bbcenter;
Platform btcenter;

ArrayList<Bullet> bullets;

//WeaponPUP weaponpup;

void setup() {

  size(1280, 720);
  frameRate(60);

  //inicia o ControlIO (vai ver que comandos estao ligados)
  controlo = ControlIO.getInstance(this);

  //procura comandos compativeis
  comando = controlo.getMatchedDevice("playerControl");
  //comando2 = controlo.getMatchedDevice("player2Control");

  //associa funçoes a botoes (Botão para Função)
  BpFp1(); //p1 = player 1
  //BpFp2();

  box2d = new Box2DProcessing(this);
  box2d.createWorld();
  box2d.setGravity(0, -90);
  box2d.listenForCollisions();

  player1 = new Player(280, 80, 39, 55);
  player2 = new Player(1000, 80, 39, 55);

  floor = new Platform(640, 720, 1300, 80);
  sideLeft = new Platform(0, 360, 1, 3280);
  sideRight = new Platform(1280, 360, 1, 3280);
  ceiling = new Platform(640, 0, 3280, 1);

  stleft = new Platform(60, 90, 240, 10);
  smleft = new Platform(60, 340, 120, 10);
  sbleft = new Platform(60, 590, 120, 10);

  stright = new Platform(1220, 90, 240, 10);
  smright = new Platform(1220, 340, 120, 10);
  sbright = new Platform(1220, 590, 120, 10);

  mbleft = new Platform(390, 520, 330, 10);
  mtleft = new Platform(390, 270, 330, 10);

  mbright = new Platform(890, 520, 330, 10);
  mtright = new Platform(890, 270, 330, 10);

  bbcenter = new Platform(640, 150, 500, 10);
  btcenter = new Platform(640, 400, 500, 10);


  bullets = new ArrayList<Bullet>();

  //weaponpup = new WeaponPUP(450, 570, 20, 20);
}

void draw() {

  background(0);
  box2d.step();

  fx1 = comando.getSlider("movX").getValue();
  //fx2 = comando2.getSlider("movX").getValue();

  floor.display();
  stleft.display();
  smleft.display();
  sbleft.display();
  stright.display();
  smright.display();
  sbright.display();
  mbleft.display();
  mtleft.display();
  mbright.display();
  mtright.display();
  bbcenter.display();
  btcenter.display();


  player1.display();
  p1Move();

  player2.display();
  p2Move();

  texts();

  //weaponpup.display();

  for (int i = 0; i<bullets.size(); i++) {
    bullets.get(i).display();
  }
}

void texts() {

  fill(255);
  textSize(16);
  textAlign(LEFT);
  text("HP: "+round(player1.hpoints), 10, 20);
  textAlign(LEFT);
  text("HP: "+round(player2.hpoints), 1220, 20);
}
```

Comment: Difícil saber o que é que está errado somente com essas informações. Isso daí é um erro genérico que veio de algum lugar do Uarma e esse erro não dá maiores detalhes sobre o que foi que deu errado, a única coisa que ele informa é que foi alguma coisa no Uarma. Você poderia postar algum trecho de código-fonte que ajude os outros a replicarem o problema?

Comment: @VictorStafusa já coloquei no post original o código-fonte. Obrigado

Comment: O erro só acontece quando você aperta o `useWep`?

Comment: O que há dentro do construtor de `Bullet`?

Comment: @VictorStafusa coloquei no post original

Comment: @VictorStafusa sim, o erro so acontece com o useWep. deve ter algo a ver com o construtor bullet nao?

Comment: Achei uma pista: https://github.com/jbox2d/jbox2d/blob/master/jbox2d-library/src/main/java/org/jbox2d/dynamics/World.java#L339 - Esse erro é causado porque o seu mundo está em um estado bloqueado. Entretanto não sei em que circunstâncias ele entra ou sai deste estado. Além disso, o ideal seria que o Box2D lançasse um `IllegalStateException` ao invés de validar o estado com um `assert`, ou que pelo menos desse alguma informação no `assert`. Entretanto, já sabemos a origem do problema, embora isso não seja o suficiente para entendê-la.

Comment: Bem, você está fazendo alguma coisa errada com a variável `box2d`. Você pode postar a classe `Meon` inteira?

Comment: @VictorStafusa já está. agradeço imensa esta ajuda!

Comment: Isso não parece ser a sua classe inteira, vez que não há `public class Meon` após os imports e nem o método `BpFp1`. Entretanto, o fato de você estar alterando o seu mundo dentro do `draw` com o `box2d.step();` me parece extremamente suspeito. Para que o mundo possa ser renderizado na tela, ele deverá estar "congelado", só podendo ser alterado fora do contexto no qual ele é desenhado. Você pode estar violando esse conceito ao acrescentar objetos no mundo enquanto ele está sendo desenhado.

Answer (score 0):

Isso é um problema de threads. O `ControlIO` utiliza a sua própria thread para receber entrada, tal como evidenciado por isso:

```
at org.gamecontrolplus.ControlIO.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Entretanto, o Box2D (por debaixo do Processing) manipula o seu mundo virtual em sua própria thread também. Você não deveria manipular mundos virtuais fora da thread utilizada pelo Box2D. Fazer isso é ariscado e pode ocasionar problemas de corrupção de dados devido a interferência desordenada entre threads.

Para protegere-se contra esse tipo de problem, o Box2D bloqueia os seus mundos virtuais para evitar manipulação inesperada. Entrenatnto ele utiliza `assert`s ao invés de `IllegalArgumentException`s ou `ConcurrentModificationException`s que a maior parte dos outros frameworks em Java utilizam para checar esse tipo de coisa. Logo, você tem um `AssertionError` sendo lançado [deste ponto do código do Box2D](https://github.com/jbox2d/jbox2d/blob/master/jbox2d-library/src/main/java/org/jbox2d/dynamics/World.java#L339).

Infelizmente, é justamente isso o que você está fazendo. Ao criar uma `Bullet`, você faz isso a partir da thread do `ControlIO` thread. O construtor de `Bullet` tenta adicionar a `Bullet` ao mundo virtual. O Box2D não gosta disso e lança o erro no `assert`.

A solução seria não criar o `Bullet` de dentro do método `Uarma`. Ao invés disso, colocar um objeto em alguma lista (com a devida sincronização) que diz que uma `Bullet` deve ser criada em uma determinada posição. De volta à sua classe `Meon` que manipula o mundo virtual na thread do Box2D, você consome a lista e adiciona as `Bullet`s correspondentes no mundo virtual ao chamar o construtor.